# How do I limit my an API response based on screen width?

Tags: jquery, shopify

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var feed = new Instafeed({
          get: 'user',
          userId: 1094499841,
          clientId: '0f6a6d6496d04eecaa5996870bb2af17',
          accessToken:    '178142608.0f6a6d6.27edbb518cad4d3eadcc7f3ec5995c45',
          resolution: 'thumbnail',
          {% if screen.width <= 900 %}
            limit: 9,
          {% else %}
            limit: 16,
          {% endif %}
          sortBy: 'most-recent'
      });
    feed.run();
});
```

I want to limit the instagram photos being pulled to 9 on mobile vs 16 on tablet or desktop. This is being done in a shopify theme.liquid file. I think what's happening is the screen width is not being detected because right now it just pulls 16 photos no matter the screen size.

Comment: do you want to change the number of images fetched based on _platform_  (tablet/desktop/mobile) or _window size_ (small/large)?  what if the user is on a desktop but their browser is not full-screen?  Might it be better to use viewport size instead of screen size, as @Oka suggested?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My experience with Liquid is limited - does [`screen` even exist](http://cheat.markdunkley.com/)?

Nevertheless, this should be possible with just JavaScript by using `window.innerWidth`, or jQuery's `.width()` method. This will give you the width of the viewport. On mobile this is usually the width of the display as well (in its current orientation!), but on a desktop this might not reflect the total width of the display.

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var feed = new Instafeed({
          /* */
          limit: (window.innerWidth <= 900 ? 9 : 16)
      });
    feed.run();
});
```

To grab a display size you can try [`window.screen.width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen/width) or [`window.screen.availWidth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen/availWidth). You generally should not care what the size of the display is - only the size of the viewport should really matter to you if you're developing for multiple devices, since the viewport size will consistently impose the constraints of your design.

I'd try to strike a balance in your design where all devices see roughly the same amount of information, regardless of size / orientation since most devices are subject to resizing, or reorientation.

A good edge case example is the iPad 2, which has a resolution of `1024x768`. What happens when a user loads your website in portrait, receives 9 images, and then rotates to landscape?

Comment: `window.innerWidth` is the width of the viewport, not the screen.  This can in some cases result in the wrong number of images fetched on a desktop.  (which may or may not be what OP wants)

Comment: @DanO Updated the answer. I think the answer to the question on getting screen sizes with JavaScript is fairly clearcut, but the implications of using those values is murky.

Comment: agreed - I think you're right when you say that it's the viewport which should matter in this case.  +1

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Oka and @DanO. You are right about the screen width vs the window width. Someone on a desktop might start off with a small window and then maximize it, in which case there would be too few photos displayed. So I decided to hide the extra photos in the CSS with a mobile media query which I was originally avoiding for some reason:

```
    #instafeed a {
      position: relative;
      float: left;
      overflow: hidden;
      width: 12.5%;
      width: -webkit-calc(100% / 8);
      width: calc(100% / 8);
      opacity: .75;
      filter: alpha(opacity=75);
      -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease;
      -moz-transition: all 200ms ease;
      -ms-transition: all 200ms ease;
      -o-transition: all 200ms ease;
      transition: all 200ms ease;
    }
@media (max-width: 768px){
  #instafeed a {
    width: -webkit-calc(100% / 3);
    width: calc(100% / 3);
    &:nth-child(10),&:nth-child(11),&:nth-child(12),&:nth-child(13),&:nth-child(14),&:nth-child(15),&:nth-child(16){
      display: none;
    }
  }
}
```